# Mock final new instance created?

Tags: java, mocking

How to mock `private final MockClass mockClass = new MockClass();`

```
 public class SimpleClass {
     private final MockClass mockClass = new MockClass();
 }
```

Comment: Depends which mocking library you are using. With PowerMock it would need a `mockStatic(MockClass.class)` call. With JMockit, you declare a `@Mocked MockClass` field or parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency injection; then you can have whatever you want in the field:

```
class SimpleClass {
  private final MockClass mockClass;

  SimpleClass(MockClass mockClass) {
    this.mockClass = mockClass;
  }
}
```

See [Misko Hevery's guide to writing testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/): your code is an example of the warning sign "new keyword in a constructor or at field declaration".

Comment: I have this case, and I want know any frameworks do the opportunity mock this case? I know code wich i write not testable, but i have this case